# Bathroom cabinet door fix

Tags: bathroom, cabinets

[image]

How on earth can I fix this cabinet door? My 13 year old used the door as a knee rest and the hinge popped out and damaged the cabinet wall. Is there a quick fix even if it's not permanent?

Comment: i would cut out/route a square of the white "board", big enough to catch the hinge's screws and remove all damaged material. then fashion a square wood "plug" the same size as your hole. 2part epoxy the patch, more is plenty, and tap it into the hole. once cured, you can re-attach the hinge to the fresh wood. paint.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! That is unfortunate.

The material is particle board and has been badly damaged. Since the cabinet is against the wall repairing it would be very difficult without removing the cabinet first.

I would try to move the hinge. Preferably, to the top of the door if you have enough space for the hinge. If not move it below the damaged area. You may have to drill very small, maybe 1/16", shallow pilot holes for the screws to get them started but you could try driving the screws without this first.

Have the 13 year old help you so he/she can learn to fix their mistakes and how much work it takes.

Good,luck!

Comment: Do you think there is any chance of fixing the damaged hinge area by removing all the damaged particle board in the area and then filling the area with a wood filler bondo type material? The filler would have to be squeezed into the remaining wall of the cabinet and flattened to the inner wall surface with a still putty knife and left to get hard. I have limited experience with this type of filler so do not know how strongly it would bond to the raw particle board. In addition I do not know how well the material holds screws.

Comment: Some of the wood fillers advertise they are drillable and are strong enough to hold screws, but the problem would probably be how strong the remaining particle board is. It doesn't start out that strong in the first place and looks like after you remove the damaged part it could be quite thin. Another possibility is to screw all the way threw the side of the cabinet with longer screws. That might hold.....maybe.